# How to use MaterialPropertyBlocks to randomly change the color of multiple materials on an object?

Tags: unity, c#, random, materials

I have a character prefab for a civilian with 5 materials. Each one should be a random color but I don't want a new material for every civilian in the game. I [asked a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133418/how-to-have-random-and-different-colors-on-multiple-objects-with-one-material/133425?noredirect=1#comment232841_133425) earlier and had a good answer. However I was pointed towards [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126568/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-object-at-runtime) with MaterialPropertyBlocks. This is the code I currently have:

```
void Start () {
    Color newShirtColor = shirtColor[Random.Range(0, shirtColor.Length)];

    MaterialPropertyBlock props = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
    props.AddColor("_Color", newShirtColor);
    GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().SetPropertyBlock(props);
}
```

It works really well but the color is assigned to the whole mesh. How can I do this for each of the 5 materials on the object so that it only changed the color for the assigned parts of the mesh, with only one material for each section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a great answer over [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-use-materialpropertyblocks-to-randomly-change-the-color-of-multiple-materials-on-an-object.443677/) at the unity forums. In short he basically said to use a texture with different colors on each channel and use that as a factor for each section of the character, thus sort of separating out the mesh, without actually separating it.