# How to get materials from objects?

Tags: unity, c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform g in waypoints[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (g.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null)
                {
                    meshRenderers.Add(g.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>());
                }

                if(g.GetComponent<Material>() != null)
                {
                    materials.Add(g.GetComponent<Material>());
                }
            }
        }
```

I can get the MeshRenderer from each object children there are like 1000 MeshRenderers.

and in the editor, I can see that each child with MeshRenderer also have a material component.  for example:

[image: meshrenderer and material]

I want to get also the Material from each child if there is any material but I'm getting 0 items in the materials List.

later on I want to manipulate the materials but first I can't even get them to a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the inspector lists the materials below the components of a gameObject, Materials are not components. So `GetComponent<Material>` is never going to return anything. The materials used by a Renderer are managed by the Renderer classes themselves and accessed through the scripting API of the [`Renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) class.

You can transfer the materials from one object to another like this:

```
 var materials = new List<Material>();
 object1.GetComponent<Renderer>().GetMaterials(materials);
 object2.GetComponent<Renderer>().SetMaterials(materials);
```

> later on I want to manipulate the materials

If that modification is only minor (as in you are changing a single texture or a single color), then I would recommend to keep the materials as they are, but [override individual material properties for each renderer using a MaterialPropertyBlock](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126568/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-object-at-runtime/126611#126611).