# How to make each waypoint individual blinking colors when the camera is reaching the waypoint?

Tags: unity, c#

The main goal is to make each waypoint blinking by changing colors when the camera is reaching the current waypoint.

The script and post are a bit long so I will put the whole script and then explain the blinking parts and what I have tried so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraPreview : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string waypointTag = "Waypoint";
    public float maxMovementSpeed = 5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 2f;
    public float distanceThreshold = 0.1f;
    public float pauseTime = 2f;

    // New public variables
    public int currentIndex;
    public string currentWaypointName;
    public Color targetColor = Color.green;
    public float blinkInterval = 0.5f;

    private Transform[] waypoints;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;
    private bool isAtWaypoint = false;
    private float currentMovementSpeed;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    private MeshRenderer[] currentWaypointRenderers;
    private Material[] originalWaypointMaterials;

    private List<MeshRenderer> meshRenderers = new List<MeshRenderer>();
    private List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();

    private enum CameraState { Rotating, Moving, Waiting }
    private CameraState currentState = CameraState.Rotating;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Find all game objects with the specified tag and store their transforms in an array
        GameObject[] waypointObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(waypointTag);
        waypoints = new Transform[waypointObjects.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            waypoints[i] = waypointObjects[i].transform;
        }

        // Sort the waypoints by name in ascending order
        System.Array.Sort(waypoints, (w1, w2) => w1.name.CompareTo(w2.name));

        targetPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint].position;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position);

        currentWaypointRenderers = new MeshRenderer[waypoints.Length];
        originalWaypointMaterials = new Material[waypoints.Length];

        // Get the renderers and materials of each waypoint's children
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {

            foreach (Transform g in waypoints[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                var renderer = g.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                if (renderer != null)
                {
                    meshRenderers.Add(renderer);
                    materials.AddRange(renderer.materials);
                }
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(WaypointTraversal());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaypointTraversal()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            currentState = CameraState.Rotating;
            yield return RotateTowardsWaypoint();

            currentState = CameraState.Moving;
            yield return MoveTowardsWaypoint();

            currentState = CameraState.Waiting;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(pauseTime);

            currentWaypoint++;
            if (currentWaypoint >= waypoints.Length)
            {
                currentWaypoint = 0;
            }

            targetPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint].position;
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position);

            // Update public variables
            currentIndex = currentWaypoint;
            currentWaypointName = waypoints[currentWaypoint].name;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateTowardsWaypoint()
    {
        float angleToTargetWaypoint = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation);
        while (angleToTargetWaypoint >= 1f)
        {
            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.rotation = newRotation;
            angleToTargetWaypoint = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveTowardsWaypoint()
    {
        float distanceToWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition);
        while (distanceToWaypoint > distanceThreshold)
        {
            float tMovement = Mathf.Clamp01(distanceToWaypoint / distanceThreshold);
            currentMovementSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(0f, maxMovementSpeed, tMovement);

            Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, currentMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position = newPosition;

            distanceToWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition);

            // Check if the camera is close to the current waypoint
            if (distanceToWaypoint <= distanceThreshold)
            {
                StartCoroutine(BlinkWaypoint());
            }

            yield return null;
        }
        isAtWaypoint = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator BlinkWaypoint()
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        int currentMaterialIndex = currentWaypoint;
        Material[] materials = currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials;

        while (elapsedTime < blinkInterval)
        {
            // Blink the waypoint by toggling its color between original and targetColor
            for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
            {
                materials[i].color = materials[i].color == targetColor ? originalWaypointMaterials[currentMaterialIndex].color : targetColor;
            }

            currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials = materials;

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        // Reset waypoint color back to its original color after blinking
        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
        {
            materials[i].color = originalWaypointMaterials[currentMaterialIndex].color;
        }

        currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials = materials;
    }
}
```

In the Start I'm getting each waypoint children of children recursive all MeshRenderer components and add it to array.  and also getting each waypoint children of children Materials.

```
currentWaypointRenderers = new MeshRenderer[waypoints.Length];
originalWaypointMaterials = new Material[waypoints.Length];

        // Get the renderers and materials of each waypoint's children
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {

            foreach (Transform g in waypoints[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                var renderer = g.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                if (renderer != null)
                {
                    meshRenderers.Add(renderer);
                    materials.AddRange(renderer.materials);
                }
            }
        }
```

It's not organized and not sorted yet, but I do get all MeshRenderers and all Materials both arrays contain about 1000 MeshRenderer components and 1000 materials.

then in the bottom of the script when the camera is reaching a waypoint and then waiting at the waypoint for some seconds, I'm start making the waypoint object blinking by changing colors:

```
// Check if the camera is close to the current waypoint
            if (distanceToWaypoint <= distanceThreshold)
            {
                StartCoroutine(BlinkWaypoint());
            }
```

and the BlinkWaypoint() method

```
private IEnumerator BlinkWaypoint()
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        int currentMaterialIndex = currentWaypoint;
        Material[] materials = currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials;

        while (elapsedTime < blinkInterval)
        {
            // Blink the waypoint by toggling its color between original and targetColor
            for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
            {
                materials[i].color = materials[i].color == targetColor ? originalWaypointMaterials[currentMaterialIndex].color : targetColor;
            }

            currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials = materials;

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        // Reset waypoint color back to its original color after blinking
        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
        {
            materials[i].color = originalWaypointMaterials[currentMaterialIndex].color;
        }

        currentWaypointRenderers[currentMaterialIndex].materials = materials;
    }
```

what I want to archive:

I want that when the camera has reached a waypoint and while the camera is waiting at the waypoint then to make that the current waypoint will blink. for example, to blink between the original materials colors and green color or between green and red.

for that I need to find the current waypoint all children that have MeshRenderer and then from each child with MeshRenderer to get the material/s and then to change the color for these materials to make the blinking effect.

I'm not sure if the way I did it it's the right way but it's not working well.  some waypoint object blinking but only in some parts only and some not blinking at all.

and because some of the waypoints are using the same original single material, I added to the camera also this script that will change in runtime each waypoint children materials names to a unique name so I can change each time only the current waypoint colors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointMaterialChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        foreach (GameObject waypoint in waypoints)
        {
            // Check the immediate children of the waypoint for a MeshRenderer with a material
            MeshRenderer[] childRenderers = waypoint.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>(true);
            if (childRenderers.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (MeshRenderer childRenderer in childRenderers)
                {
                    // Check if the child renderer has a material
                    if (childRenderer.material != null)
                    {
                        // Duplicate the existing material for each child
                        Material newMat = new Material(childRenderer.sharedMaterial);
                        newMat.name = $"{waypoint.name}_Material"; // Create a unique name for the material

                        // Assign the new material to the child
                        childRenderer.material = newMat;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a thousand objects in your game which you only want to look differently *some* of the time, then it is probably not a good idea to create an unique material for every single one of them. Switching between materials when rendering different objects is expensive for the rendering engine. You would probably get much better performance if you keep the same material on every object and [use a MaterialPropertyBlock to change their current color](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126568/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-object-at-runtime/126611#126611) when you need to.

Comment: Or if you really want to do this with materials instead of property blocks: I noted that you really only have two different material settings: on and off. So you really should need only two materials that can be shared between objects: one for the on-state and one for the off-state.

Comment: But to get to your actual problem: "some waypoint object blinking but only in some parts only and some not blinking at all." hints that the problem is probably somewhere in your logic to determine what waypoint should be blinking and what waypoint shouldn't. That's where I would recommend to start debugging.